# List records where absolute difference between current epochtimestamp and epochtimestamp in file is greater than 48 hours

Tags: perl

I am using the following script to list the details of Jobs from the Input file : backup_report.txt.

The fourth field in the report (represented by $data[6]) is epoch timestamp. The following command converted this to readable timestamp ( $data[6]=scalar(localtime($data[6]));)

How to display only those records where timestamp is greater than 48 hours (currenttimestamp(epoch format)-$data[6](epoch format)/3600 should be greater than 48)

Also the timestamp needs to be converted to readable format.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, "<", "backup_report.txt" or die $!;
open my $outputfile, ">", "active_jobs.txt" or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
    no warnings 'numeric';
    chomp $line;
    my @data = split (' ', $line);
    if ($data[1] == 0 and $data[2] == 1)
      {
         $data[6]=scalar(localtime($data[6]));
         print $outputfile "$data[0] $data[3] $data[5] $data[6] \n";
       }
}
 close $fh;
 close $outputfile;
```

Input file :

```
237576 0 1 GYTFRUIP01_TYOEPUK_RMAN Default-Application-Backup prtygrf01   1442149024 0000000055 1442149079 23328
237575 0 1 GYTFRUIP01_TYOEPUK_RMAN Default-Application-Backup prtygrf01 1442148956 0000000053 1442149009 2848
237574 0 3 GYTFRUIP01_TYOEPUK_RMAN Default-Application-Backup prtygrf01 1442148954 0000000045 1442148999 544
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean that you want to skip the lines that are younger than 48 hours.

The math you suggested is a bit complicated. You can [just call `time`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html). It will return the current unix timestamp (which is *epoch*). Now substract the *epoch* value that you've got in `$data[6]` before your conversion. If that's greater than 48 hours (which is `3600 * 48`), you [skip using `next`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $timestamp = 1442149024;
say 'old' if time - $timestamp > 48 * 3600;
```

I'd put that after the `split` like this.

```
my @data = split (' ', $line);
next if time - $data[6] > 48 * 3600;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have achieved the results.

Comment: I did clicked on checkmark. Also I would like to add following : "#######Active Jobs#######" in the beginning of the file : active_jobs.txt. How can I do this. Please help since I started working on PERL from today :)

Comment: @RahulM you already know how to `print` to you `$outputfile`. Just do that right after the `open`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use for the Unix filter model (read from STDIN, write to STDOUT).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $two_days = 48 * 60 * 60;

while (<>) {
  my @data = split;

  if ($data[1] == 0 and $data[2] == 1 and
    $data[6] < (time - $two_days)) {
      print "$data[0] $data[3] $data[5] " .
            localtime($data[6]) . "\n";
  }
}
```

Call it as:

```
$ ./filter_program < in_file > out_file
```